# ffmpeg doesn't render a full url, not a protocol part

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-processing

I want to render an url in a video via ffmpeg. This works well:

```
ffmpeg -i test.mp4 -vf drawtext="fontfile=[......]: text='example.com': [..........]
```

But this renders only the "https" and nothing else:

```
ffmpeg -i test.mp4 -vf drawtext="fontfile=[......]: text='https://example.com': [..........]
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Escape the colon (but consult your doctor first)

```
text='https\://example.com': [..........]
```